# Surface Integral problem involving harmonic function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I want to prove that if $\triangle f=0$ where $f$ is defined on
an open set $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{2}$, then, if $D$ is a compact circle
of center $p$ and radius $r>0$, we have for all $p\in D$:

$$f\left(p\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi r}\int_{\partial D}f \,\mathrm ds.$$

I think it should be done with the Green's theorem, because is in
$\mathbb{R}^{2}$, and both Gauss (divergence) and Stokes theorem
are for 3 variables, but I don't know how to use it in this case.
Any ideas? Thank you in advance!!

Comment: Perform a change of variables to center the disk at $0$ with radius $1$, then differentiate there.

Comment: Does $\triangle f$ denote the rotation of $f$?

Comment: Pretty sure they mean the Laplacian

Comment: I mean the laplacian

Comment: Are you looking for an answer or just hints?

Comment: @cmk what do you mean by "differentiate there"?

Comment: After performing that change of variables, you will have an integrand that depends on the radius and bounds that do not. You can differentiate that directly. Then, you can transform back and use one of Green's identities.

Comment: Okay, let me try to add a more detailed hint: Look at the right-hand side as a function of $r$, and use the change of variables $y=p+rz$ (where $y$ is the previous integration variable). Differentiate that in $r$. Then, try to reverse the change of variables and use one of Green's identities. You should get that the right-hand side is constant in $r$. What can you conclude from this?